# Use Find & Execute in Visual Basic to delete all superscripts in a Word document

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-word, superscript

I need to delete all superscripts in a Word document (actually, in hundreds of word documents)--not replace with anything or convert to full-size font, just delete.  Some of them may be footnotes/endnotes, others just ordinary superscript font (no fields).  This is just one part of a larger `VB` program.

1. Why can't I get the code below to work?  No error message,
   but it doesn't seem to actually do anything.  I've tried numerous variations on this, but to no avail.
2. I wonder if it's possible to do this with `Regex`...I understand `Regex` will find
   superscript *numbers* ({No}), but I'm not sure it will do that for
   *letters*. But to be honest, I struggle enough with Find.Execute; I
   don't think I could begin to understand how to use Regex.
   `

   ```
   With oDoc.Range.Find
   .ClearFormatting()
   .Font.Superscript = True
   .Text = "*"
   .Replacement.Text = ""
   .Forward = True
   .Format = True
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = False
   .MatchAllWordForms = False
   .MatchSoundsLike = False
   .MatchWildcards = True
   End With
   oDoc.Range.Find.Execute(FindText:="*", Replace:=True, ReplaceWith:="",    Forward:=True, MatchWildcards:=True)`
   ```

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

The `Replace` parameter requires one of the values below, not true / false.

> ```
> wdReplaceNone   Replace no occurrences.
> wdReplaceOne    Replace the first occurrence encountered.
> wdReplaceAll    Replace all occurrences.
> ```
>
> From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdreplace(v=office.14).aspx) - also see [Execute method parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/find-execute-method-word?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

---

Taking that fix into account and removing duplicate parameters, this is the resulting code block.

```
With oDoc.Find                      ' notice I changed this from oDoc.Range.Find since
    .ClearFormatting                ' the example I worked with was a single word doc.
    .Font.Superscript = True
    .Text = "*"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll)
End With
```